# Can changes in the same file be split to different commits in git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-extensions

*Sorry if there is a duplicate for this somewhere, I drowned in a flood of tricks to change commit messages (which doesn't help me) when searching for a solution to this.*

I have **two sets of changes** that should be part of **one commit each**. Unfortunately, I started the second changeset in the morning, not noticing that I had forgotten to commit the first one in the evening before.

In most cases, they affect different files. However, there is **one file that contains changes for both changesets** which break the build if pushed without the second changeset. Too bad I want to work on that on a separate branch until functional.

Sadly, I had already **committed (not pushed)** the first changeset and created the work **branch** on top of it when I noticed that there was a file containing changes for both.

**Is there a way to edit my commit such that I can extract the changes affecting changeset 2?**

In Mercurial, you could untangle commits by

1. converting them to patches,
2. opening them in a text editor and
3. moving lines of diff between the patch files (if your Mercurial GUI was not open at the time).

When the GUI was reopened, the patches contained what they were supposed to, could be finalized and pushed.

That's actually the workflow I am aiming for. Is there anything similar for git?

Tools I am using: TortoiseGit and GitExtensions on Win10

**Edit: solution as suggested in the answer**

```
git checkout new_branch
git reset -p HEAD~1
git add -p
...
git commit -m "my changeset 1"
git add
git commit -m "my changeset 2"
git checkout old_branch
git reset --hard <new_branch>~1
```

Which gives me `old_branch` at changeset 1 and `new_branch` at changeset 2.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `git add -p` to selectively stage changes/hunks that you plan to commit.  After you commit the first batch, you may be left with the second set of changes in which case you can just add the file as normal and commit.

Git will ask what you want to do with each commit.  Type '?' for help.  Press 'y' to stage the hunk and 'n' to disclude the hunk from your staging area.

In the case where git doesn't select a hunk at a fine enough grain, when it asks you what to do with the hunk, you can press 'e' and your editor will open and you can choose which parts of the hunk you want to include.

Learned about this recently and it's been incredibly useful.

Comment: Thanks for the pre-emptive solution! Will definitely note that down for the future. Is there a way to remove the changes from an already committed changeset?

Comment: @TinyT There is a `git reset -p` to unstage in hunks (so it removes things from the staging/index area)

Comment: thanks, it worked using `git reset -p HEAD~1` on the new branch (using option `a` for them all, because I didn't want to discard any), then committing the changes in correct order (using GUI commit tool killed the git add -p settings, unfortunately, so I had to copy the post-version of my mixed file, undo changeset 2, commit changeset 1, overwrite the file, and commit changeset 2), and then performing a hard reset of my old branch to changeset 1, discarding the other faulty commit (which was on both branches).